# LSTM forecasting with single categorical feature

Tags: python, deep-learning, time-series, lstm, forecasting

I'm pretty new to time series. 
This is the dataset I'm working on:

```
           Date   Price               Location
0    2012-01-01  1771.0                 Marche
1    2012-01-01  1039.0               Calabria
2    2012-01-01  2193.0               Campania
3    2012-01-01  2015.0         Emilia-Romagna
4    2012-01-01  1483.0  Friuli-Venezia Giulia
...         ...     ...                    ...
2475 2022-04-01  1963.0                  Lazio
2476 2022-04-01  1362.0  Friuli-Venezia Giulia
2477 2022-04-01  1674.0         Emilia-Romagna
2478 2022-04-01  1388.0                 Marche
2479 2022-04-01  1103.0                Abruzzo
```

I'm trying to build an LSTM for price prediction, but I don't know how to manage the **Location** categorical feature: do I have to use one-hot encoding or a groupby?
What I want to predict is the price based on the location. 
How can I achieve that? A Python solution is particularly appreciated.

Thanks in advance.

Comment: You can simply use OHE. You can also use the geographical coordinates of the region, if you think that the position is relevant in the prediction.

Comment: @SalvatoreDanieleBianco and what about the splitting? I think I can't use the classic 70-30 right?

Comment: Do you have just one time series? or more? How about the length? 2480?

Comment: For each region I have the months from 2012 to now (excluding May), so something like:
<br>
2020-01-01 - price - Sicilia <br>
2020-02-01 - price - Sicilia

And so on

Comment: Ok got it. In this case my hint is to consider the different region prices as different features to obtain a dataset of shape `(T, 20)`, where `T` is the number of time-data and `20` is the number of regions. For the train-test splitting you can use 80-20, where the test 20% is the very last part of the time series.

Comment: @SalvatoreDanieleBianco can you help me out? From the name I guess that you're italian too ;)

Comment: yes I'm Italian too :D Provide in the text a reproducible example (for example 15 time-points for just 5 regions) and I will be glad to help you. If you prefer you can provide random Prices.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/244607/discussion-between-salvatore-danilo-palumbo-and-salvatore-daniele-bianco).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Suppose my dataset (`df`) is analogous to yours:

```
          Date       Price  Location
0   2021-01-01  791.076890  Campania
1   2021-01-01  705.702464  Lombardia
2   2021-01-01  719.991382  Sicilia
3   2021-02-01  825.760917  Lombardia
4   2021-02-01  747.734309  Sicilia
...        ...         ...        ...
31  2021-11-01  886.874348  Lombardia
32  2021-11-01  935.040583  Campania
33  2021-12-01  771.165378  Sicilia
34  2021-12-01  952.255227  Campania
35  2021-12-01  939.754515  Lombardia
```

In my case I have a `Price` record for 3 regions (Campania, Lombardia, Sicilia) every month. My Idea is to treat the different region as different features, so I would transform `df` as:

```
df = df.set_index(["Date", "Location"]).Price.unstack()
```

Now my dataset is like:

```
Location    Campania    Lombardia   Sicilia
Date            
2021-01-01  791.076890  705.702464  719.991382
2021-02-01  758.872755  825.760917  747.734309
2021-03-01  880.038005  803.165998  837.738419
       ...         ...         ...         ...
2021-10-01  908.402345  805.081193  792.369610
2021-11-01  935.040583  886.874348  736.862025
2021-12-01  952.255227  939.754515  771.165378
```

Please, after this, make sure there are no `NaN` values (`df.isna().sum()`).

Now you can pass this data to a multi feature RNN (or LSTM), as made in [this example](https://machinelearningmastery.com/multivariate-time-series-forecasting-lstms-keras/), or to a multi-channel 1D-CNN (choosing an appropriate kernel size). The only problem in both cases could be the small size of the dataset, so try to not to over-parameterize the model (for example reducing the number of neurons and layers), otherwise the over-fitting will be unavoidable. About this you can test the model on the last 20% of your time-series:

```
from sklearn.model_selection import train_test_split
df_train, df_test = train_test_split(df, shuffle=False, test_size=.2)
```

The last part is to build a matching `(X, Y)` for the supervised learning, but this depends on what model are you using and what is your prediction task. [Another example here](https://towardsdatascience.com/lstm-for-google-stock-price-prediction-e35f5cc84165).